# getting error message on jquery "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[situation]**

hello, I'm trying to copy an html tag into a variable and paste it later on the another section. Now I'm getting an error message below:

**[error message]**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
> at Function.se.contains (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at ie (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at Function.clone (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at HTMLDocument. (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2
> at Function.map (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at S.fn.init.map (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at S.fn.init.clone (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
> at HTMLInputElement. (:4:15)
> at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)

**[my code]**

```
<script>
    var shianimg;
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#cloner").click(function(){
        shianimg = $(".dz-image-preview img").html;
        console.log(shianimg);
    });
    });
</script>
```

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#clonee").click(function(){
  $(shianimg).clone().show().appendTo("#shian","#shian1","#shian2","#shian3","#shian4","#shian5","#shian6","#shian7","#shian8","#shian9");
});
    });
</script>
```

can you please help me find what is wrong?

Comment: You never invoke the html() method ...missing `()`. After that it really doesn't make sense have multiple selectors in appendTo. Not clear what intent is there

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call jQuery's `html()` method without parenthesis, so that the result will be the method itself, not the selected element's inner HTML. When you call the `clone()` and `show()` methods on that result and try to append it to an element, you get the mentioned error.

```
$(".dz-image-preview img").html // Wrong
```

You could store a copy of the element instead of its HTML content (which is `""`, since images cannot have inner HTML).

```
$(".dz-image-preview img").clone() // Right
```